# Delete lines from file, then save/overwrite original file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a time series data file that sometimes generates "0.00" values in certain fields. I want to write a script that checks the file and deletes all rows that contain a "0.00" value. I managed to read the file, delete the lines and save in a different file. 
However, I need the original file to be overwritten. This is because another software package is working with this specific file where I can't use these "0.00" values.

This is what I got:

```
def remove_line(line, stop):
    return any([word in line for word in stop])

stop = ["0.00"]
with open("7290_0.dat", "r") as f, open("7290_1.dat", "w") as w: 
    for line in f:
        if not remove_line(line, stop):
            w.write(line)
```

Thanks in advance for your advise.

Comment: Just do nested **with statement** instead with the same filename

Comment: You could call `shutil.copyfile` afterwards, then delete `7290_1.dat`.

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx This will fail at least on Windows and probably on most OS'

Comment: All you need is adding `os.rename("7290_1.dat", "7290_0.dat")` after the `with` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read lines and write necessary lines to same file again.

```
stop = "0.00"
with open("7290_0.dat", "r") as f: 
    lines = f.readlines()

with open("7290_0.dat", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        if stop not in line:
            f.write(line)
```

If you have limited buffer, you can also do the following:

```
stop = "0.00"
lines = []
with open("7290_0.dat", "r") as f:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    if stop not in line:
        lines.append(line)


with open("7290_0.dat", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

The canonical, safe, tested solution is to write to a new file as you already do, then replace the original with the new one (using `os.rename()`).

This avoids loading the whole file in memory and a lot of potential other issues (race conditions etc), and make sure you won't loose data if anything crashes before the rename operation.

**EDIT**: as mentionned by Michael Butscher, on Windows you might need to delete the original file (using `os.remove()`) before doing the  `os.rename()`.

Comment: Rename with an existing file as target will fail on Windows and maybe other OS'

Comment: Works on Linux, I didn't test on Windows indeed - but then you just have to delete the original before renaming.